# Minimum number of swaps required to have an alternating array

Tags: algorithms

We are given an array with only $0$s and $1$s. The number of $0$s is greater or equal to the number of $1$s. The goal is to ensure that there is not a pair of $1$s adjacent to each other. We can only read the value of an element or to swap 2 elements. What is an algorithm for the fewest swaps possible?
I tried swapping central elements in any $0011$s and $1100$s first, then finding $000$s, saving their positions in an auxillary array, then putting them wherever we could not do $0011$ or $1100$ swap, but to both orders of these operations there were counterexamples.
The exercise is a preparatory one for a test, but it was marked as harder and no one in my class was able to solve it.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?  What's the context in which you encountered this problem? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercise-style problems for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Go through the toolbox of algorithm design techniques you have learned in that course, and try to apply one after the other.

Comment: We learned how to do it in linear time complexity, not how to minimise the number of swaps.